# Phonegap with Restful webservice

Tags: jquery, html, rest, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and restful webservice. my question is how can i fuse the both of them so that i have an application that would sync with the restful webservice. i have tried a sample restful service with jsonp but phonegap doesn't loads the service or maybe i'm missing something. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code help you understand how to call a web service and and parse it to display the results

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function bodyload(){
    alert("We are calling jquery's ajax function and on success callback xml parsing are done");
$.ajax({  
    url:'http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml',  
    dataType:'application/xml', 
    timeout:10000,  
    type:'POST',  
    success:function(data) {
        $("#bookInFo").html("");
         $("#bookInFo").append("<hr>");
         $(data).find("Book").each(function () {
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br> Name: " + $(this).find("name").text());
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br> Address: " + $(this).find("address").text());
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br> Country: " + $(this).find("country").text());
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br><hr>");
         });
     },  
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
      alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
      alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
      alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
      $( "#bookInFo" ).append( XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
    }
    });
}   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyload()">
<button onclick="bodyload()">Ajax call</button>
<p id="bookInFo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. i already did something like that but the problem is that when i run phonegap on an android emulator it doesn't fetch any data (i've included an alert to show that it works but the alert event doesn't fire.)

Comment: i already figured that out to my surprise it is still not working. does it have a problem on working locally? because i'm still running it on my emulator and the rest service locally.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same as normal web project (using JSON):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://...',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: data,
success: : function(data) {
//...
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//...
},
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
}
});
```

The only difference is in PhoneGap you don't have to worry about same origin policy problems. That makes usage of JSONP not really necessary. Unless you are working with a server which only processes JSONP and not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your ajax call slightly like this. We need to get the request posted. Also jquery.js should be first. Try to call device ready function too.

```
$.ajax({  
    url:'http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml',  
    dataType:'xml', 
    type:'get',
    cache: false,
```